# calculate the average value in a certain time interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, average

I have a table in which values are written every 30 minutes
I want to calculate the average value over a certain time period over several days.

```html
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#TABLE_1](
[numreq] [int] NULL,
[rangetime] [nvarchar](300) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

insert into [dbo].[#TABLE_1] values('2','2019-03-10 12:00:00.000')
insert into [dbo].[#TABLE_1] values('3','2019-03-10 12:30:00.000')
insert into [dbo].[#TABLE_1] values('4','2019-03-10 13:00:00.000')
insert into [dbo].[#TABLE_1] values('5','2019-03-10 13:30:00.000')
insert into [dbo].[#TABLE_1] values('6','2019-03-11 12:00:00.000')
insert into [dbo].[#TABLE_1] values('7','2019-03-11 12:30:00.000')
insert into [dbo].[#TABLE_1] values('8','2019-03-11 13:00:00.000')
insert into [dbo].[#TABLE_1] values('9','2019-03-11 13:30:00.000')
```

I wrote a sql query, but it does not give the desired result

```html
select avg([numreq]),[rangetime]
from [dbo].[#TABLE_1]
group by [rangetime]
```

The result I want to get:

```html
numreq rangetime
4  12:00
5  12:30
6  13:00
7  13:30
```

Comment: SELECT and GROUP BY the time portion of your date time field.   See the flagged duplicate for how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cast()` to parse only time :

```
select avg(numreq), cast(rangetime as time) as rangetime
from [#TABLE_1]  t
group by cast(rangetime as time);
```

If the `rangetime` has not desired type then you can use `substring()`:

```
substring(rangetime, 12, len(rangetime))
```